# how to convert a String of int into a table int[]

Tags: java, integer, int

I made a function that requires an `int[]`, `Conflict(int[] tab)`, and as you all know we extract information from a `JTextField` in the form of an `String` (s) ,so I then convert in into an integer with:

```
int input=Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Now, I found this way to do it :

```
int input= 1234;
String input= String.valueOf(input);
Vector<int> tab = new Vector<int>();
for (int cpt = 0; cpt <input.length(); cpt++)
{
    tab.add(Integer.valueOf(input.substring(cpt, cpt+1)).intValue());
}
```

but I'm looking for a simple way without the vector ,so again the Question is How can I convert the input (int) into a table of `int[]` so that I can use it in the Conflict function?

Here is an answer to my question for all of you who's looking to turn an `int` into an `int[]` using a string with a very smart simple trick

```
tcst = ""+inputc;
int tcn = tcst.length();
int[] tctab = new int[tcn];
for(int h=0; h<tcn; h++){
    tctab[h] = (int) Integer.parseInt("" + tcst.charAt(h));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a String of number like "12345" best way is to convert it into char array using toCharArray() method of string. Once you get a char array of numbers these char can be used as integer in you program. just when you get an element from the char array and convert it into int by using getNumericValue() method of character

Comment: -1 blatantly incorrect. Casting a char to an int returns to unicode position, not the numeric value.  Which is clearly not what the OP asked.

Comment: you can use getNumericValue() method of char

Comment: you can also do something like char vlaue - 48 so that you can get actual value

Answer (score -1):

If your input is a String (from a `JTextField`), then I don't see why you're converting it to an integer, just to convert it to a `String` again.

To go from `String` to `int[]`, here's a way to do it.

```
char[] chars = inputString.toCharArray();
int[] result = new int[chars.length];
for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
  result[i] = Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]);
}
```